# Sending data through python-socketio but unable to receive data on flask socketio

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am trying to send data from client where I am using python-socketio as mentioend below

```
#Client.py
import time
import socketio
sio = socketio.Client(engineio_logger=True)
start_timer = None

# if __name__ == '__main__':
sio.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
sio.wait()
sio.emit('connect', {"Data": "Device_id"})
```

and trying to on server which is using flask-socketio as mentioned below in code

```
#Server.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
app = Flask(__name__)
# app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "Social Distance Secret"
socket_app = SocketIO(app)


@socket_app.on('connect')
def handle_id(data):
    print(data)
    print(request.sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket_app.run(app, debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=3000)
```

I am able to receive the sid but I am not able to fetch the parameters I have given in client.py while emitting to WebSocket

```
# Error Server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\varul.jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\engineio\server.py", line 545, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[event](*args)
  File "C:\Users\varul.jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 721, in _handle_eio_connect
    return self._handle_connect(sid, '/')
  File "C:\Users\varul.jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 626, in _handle_connect
    self.environ[sid])
  File "C:\Users\varul.jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 708, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
  File "C:\Users\varul.jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio-4.3.1.dev0-py3.6.egg\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 283, in _handler
    *args)
  File "C:\Users\varul.jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio-4.3.1.dev0-py3.6.egg\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 711, in _handle_event
    ret = handler()
TypeError: handle_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'


# Errors client.py:
Attempting polling connection to http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?transport=polling&EIO=3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/varul.jain/Desktop/people_counter/listenn.py", line 12, in <module>
    sio.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
  File "C:\Users\varul.jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\socketio\client.py", line 279, in connect
    six.raise_from(exceptions.ConnectionError(exc.args[0]), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Unexpected status code 401 in server response
```

any suggestion will be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is that you are using a `connect` event, but this event is reserved. Change the event name to something else:

```
@socket_app.on('connected')
def handle_id(data):
    print(data)
    print(request.sid)
```

The second problem is that in your client you are calling `wait()`, which blocks until the connection ends, so your `emit()` call will never get to run. Send the emit before the wait instead:

```
sio.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
sio.emit('connected', {"Data": "Device_id"})
sio.wait()
```